# Any good (free) video tutorials on the basics of Adobe Premier Elements?

Tags: video, editing, adobe-premiere

I purchased a copy of Adobe Premier Elements with my computer earlier this year and haven't spent more than a few minutes working with it since. I want to perform some basic editing of home videos but always feel somewhat lost when using Elements. Does anyone know of any good video tutorials?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way it's Adobe *Premiere* Elements not Adobe Premier Elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start at [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=adobe+premiere+elements&search_type=&aq=f) when I'm looking for videos.

Comment: Good suggestion...not sure why I never thought to look there. I found plenty of good videos. I also discovered Adobe TV (tv.adobe.com), which I didn't know existed either.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it almost seems too obvious. But there is some really cool stuff on YouTube.